# Bitrix phinx создание таблицы

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть вот такой код

```
public function up(){
    try {
        $oConnection = \Bitrix\Main\Application::getConnection();

        $oConnection->query(sql:'CREATE TABLE `b_new_table` (`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY );');
    }
    catch (\Exception $e){
        throw new Exception( messasge:'Error create table');
    }
}
```

Phpstorm  постоянно ругается на `sql:` и `messasge:` однако на уроке никаких ошибок не было.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это блин подсказки шторма `sql:`, `messasge:`, зачем вы их в код-то написали?

Comment: добавил скриншот. Или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: PHPStorm что говорит на выделенные желтым строки?

Comment: Слова `messasge:`, `sql:` что показаны у вас на скриншоте - это подсказка PHPStorm об имени аргумента и ее не надо в свой код вставлять.

Comment: На видео не показано. У меня undefined constant sql

Comment: Все понял. Большое спасибо.

Comment: почемуто таблица не создается, sql запрос пишу правильно и с ошибками - говорит All done Exception не ловится. А когда ошибка в синтаксисе- PHP PARSE Error

Comment: Если эксепшен не ловится значит его либо ничто не бросает, либо тип эксепшена в `catch` не тот.

Comment: Заработало. Руками создал таблицу потом через phinx rollback удалил и миграция заработала.